# Moving children forms on timer tick after main form loaded

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms

I'm starting a program in VB.net where I really need to do nice animations for forms opening and closing.

Right now, I have a parent Form that is used a a "background" for the application while it can open other forms inside.
Two forms will be loaded on the application opening and I want the first one to drift to the left to the wanted position then the second one comes from underneath and drift it's location on the right.

The goal is to make it so it look something like this

```
_______________    _______________
|    _____    |    | _____  ____ |
|    |   |    |    | |   |  | B| |
|    | A |    | To | | A |  |__| |
|    |___|    |    | |___|       |
|_____________|    |_____________|
```

Right know I tried to instantly load up the two forms at the parent, then place them in the middle of the screen and starting a timer so that each tick makes the form drift left, and when it's on position, the other goes right.

Here is the code when Parent Form load

```vb
Dim WithEvents tmr As New Timer 

Private Sub Fr_Parent_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    IsMdiContainer = True

    Dim FrTicket As New FrTicket()
    FrTicket.MdiParent = Me
    FrTicket.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
    FrTicket.Show()


    Dim FrIdentite As New FrIdentite()
    FrIdentite.MdiParent = Me
    FrIdentite.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
    FrIdentite.Show()

    Dim HautEcran As Integer
    Dim LargEcran As Integer
    LargEcran = CInt(System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width.ToString())
    HautEcran = CInt(System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height.ToString())
    Dim LargFrmSite As Integer = FrIdentite.Width
    Dim hautFrmSite As Integer = FrIdentite.Height

    FrIdentite.Location = New Point((LargEcran / 2 - LargFrmSite / 2), (HautEcran / 2 - hautFrmSite / 2))
    FrTicket.Location = New Point((LargEcran / 2 - LargFrmSite / 2), (HautEcran / 2 - hautFrmSite / 2))

    tmr.Start()

End Sub
```

And then the one that is used on Tick

```
Private Sub tmr_Tick()

    Dim HautEcran As Integer
    Dim LargEcran As Integer
    LargEcran = CInt(System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width.ToString())
    HautEcran = CInt(System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height.ToString())
    Dim LargFrmSite As Integer = FrIdentite.Width
    Dim hautFrmSite As Integer = FrIdentite.Height

    Dim xIdenLoc As Integer = CInt(LargEcran / 2 - (LargFrmSite * 1.01))
    Dim yIdenLoc As Integer = CInt(HautEcran / 2 - hautFrmSite / 2)
    Dim xTicketLoc As Integer = CInt(LargEcran / 2 + (LargFrmSite * 1.01) - LargFrmSite)
    Dim yTicketLoc As Integer = CInt(HautEcran / 2 - hautFrmSite / 2)
    Dim TheLocalisationOfIden As Integer = FrIdentite.Location.X

    If TheLocalisationOfIden >= xIdenLoc Then
        FrIdentite.Location = New Point(TheLocalisationOfIden - 1, yIdenLoc)
        FrTicket.Location = New Point(TheLocalisationOfIden - 1, yTicketLoc)
    Else
        If FrTicket.Location.X <= xTicketLoc Then
            FrTicket.Location = New Point(TheLocalisationOfIden + 1, yTicketLoc)
        Else
            tmr.Stop()
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

But they actually pop up at they first localisation (Figure one) and ... Nothing.

EDIT :
Here is the last Tick code. The variables are now declared before the subs

```
Private Sub tmr_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmr.Tick

    TheLocalisationOfIden = TheLocalisationOfIden - 2
    TheLocalisationOfIden = TheLocalisationOfTicket + 2

    If TheLocalisationOfIden <= xIdenLoc Then
        FrIdentite.Location = New Point(TheLocalisationOfIden, yIdenLoc)
    Else
        If FrTicket.Location.X >= xTicketLoc Then
            FrTicket.Location = New Point(TheLocalisationOfTicket, yTicketLoc)
        Else
            tmr.Stop()
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things are missing: tmr properties and tmr event handler
In

```
Private Sub Fr_Parent_Load
```

add tmr properties (like tmr.Enabled and tmr.Interval)
and then modify the tmr event handler like this:

```
Private Sub tmr_Tick() Handles tmr.Tick
```

Comment: Just added the properties and Handles and now the MsgBox pop up, so that's a huge step forward BUT the forms still doesn't moves. I also declared my variables before the load sub cause they were reseting at each tick

Comment: set a debug breakpoint in the tick event handler and go ahead one step at a time. See what happens. I suspect this line is wrong:    TheLocalisationOfIden = TheLocalisationOfTicket + 2

Comment: Nothing happens ... That's the thing :/

Comment: Will you upload the project somewhere so that I can take a look?